# How to find values from another JSON object

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I have set of `json` objects.

1. Languages
2. User Details

User Details have the languages field - which have more than 1 values. 
Here is my sample json

```
 $scope.languages = [
            {id: 1, text: 'English'},
            {id: 2, text: 'French'},
            {id: 3, text: 'Hindi'},
            {id: 4, text: 'Telugu'}
          ];

    $scope.users = [{name: 'first user', status: 1,language:"1"},
                    {name: 'second user', status: 2,language:"1,2"},
                    {name: 'third user', status: 3,language:"1,3,4"}];
```

In my view i want to list the user name and languages.

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.name}} -  {{testString}}</li>
```

I know to do for single value. But for multiple values. I have the logic but i don't know how to implement. I am thinking that. First i have to split the user language string and change into array and then find the index of the language id and then return the language text.

I have the code to return language name from ID.

```
var foundItem = $filter('filter')($scope.languages, { id: 3  }, true)[0];
var index = $scope.languages.indexOf(foundItem );
$scope.result = $scope.languages[index].text;
```

So now the problem is how to print the languages next to the user name?

I tried like this

```
$scope.testString = function() {
    return "return test string";
}

{{testString}}
```

But its not working. If this works we can pass the langugae codes as parameter and i can add the search code inside the testString function.

Thanks

Comment: First, testString is a method, then you should call {{testString()}}

Comment: {{testString}} is not working because testString is a function, so you need to do {{ testString() }}. Regarding your original problem, it is a general javascript problem, not an angular-specific one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`testString` is a function so you cannot use it like `{{testString}}`, you have to call that function `{{testString()}}`

You can simplify your code like this.

```
    $scope.getLanguages = function (langs) {
      var l = [];
      angular.forEach(langs.split(','), function (lang) {
        l.push(findLanguageTextById(parseInt(lang)));
      })
      return l.join(', ');
    }    
    function findLanguageTextById (langId) {
      for(var i = 0;i<$scope.languages.length;i++) {
        if ($scope.languages[i].id == langId) {
          return $scope.languages[i].text;
        }
      }
    }
```

I have created a working demo for your problem take a look.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Cdl8y58IExoVSZV6lp76?p=preview

Comment: Thanks.. It works.. I am implementing the search functionality in the testString function. Please wait for few minutes, I will accept the answer once i done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not calling the function,

```
$scope.testString = (function() {
    return "return test string";
})();
```